# Can you help me find a fractal drawing program?

Tags: fractals

In a previous course on chaos, the professor had us experiment with a program. The program allowed you to draw a base image (with microsoft paint like tools), then it would iterate that image under various popular fractals. Note: The program was browser based. I have two old GIFs (with similar base image), which demonstrates what the program outputs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ2ve.gif

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO1BU.gif

Has anyone seen/heard of this?

Thanks, Austin

Comment: I've never heard of this, but a quick Octave script should do the job.

Comment: Just to be clearer: to obtain this result, draw your image, import it in Octave as a matrix, use an IFS-like script to duplicate it as many times as you wish, then glue the resulting images with e.g. the GIMP to obtain the animated GIF.

Comment: Here is a quick code I wrote some time ago to draw IFS fractals with Octave. I do not have the time to adapt it to your case, but hopefully you can start with this and adapt it to work with multiple points (=the image) instead of just one.

Comment: function fract(C,m)
n=size(C)(1)/2;
for j=1:n dets(j,1)=abs(det([C(2*j-1,1),C(2*j-1,2);C(2*j,1),C(2*j,2)])); endfor;
dets=max(dets,max(dets)/(25*n));
dets=dets/sum(dets);
L=0; for k=1:n p(k,1)=L; L=L+dets(k); endfor;
vect=zeros(m+21,2);
x=[rand,rand];
vect(1,:)=x;
for k=1:20+m
 r=rand;
 i=sum(p<r);
 x=([C(2*i-1,1) C(2*i-1,2);C(2*i,1) C(2*i,2)]*x'+[C(2*i-1,3);C(2*i,3)])';
 vect(k+1,:)=x;
endfor;
plot(vect(20:end,1),vect(20:end,2),'k.');
axis('off');
endfunction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Deterministic IFS" applet on [this Yale course page](http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/) seems to fit the description.

- You start with an input image
- You enter rules for the transformation
- The software applies the transformation, one step at a time. You can follow along to see the fractal generation.
- It is a Java applet, so is/can be browser based.